# Mapbox Autosuggest JS Filter full addresses

Tags: javascript, mapbox, autofill

When using the mapbox js autofill component, I am trying to only retrieve full addresses and not include streets / highways in the autosuggest response.

How do I initialize autofill to only include full addresses?

```
    autofillCollection = mapboxsearch.autofill({
        options: { 
            country: 'us',
            language: 'en', 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want the auto-suggestion box to only suggest full addresses like:
`123 Main St., Town, State 02123` 

vs.

`Main St., Town, State 02123`

Comment: Doesnt the Pure Autofill do this already?